# Video editor with time stretch and direct copy

Tags: windows, video, video-editing

I'm looking for a simple video editing software for Windows 7 with the following requirements:

1. Given a high-fps video (120fps), there is a simple tool to make a time stretch on a desired interval with smooth transition and correct audio stretching (no funny voices).
2. Recompression artifacts are minimized. Ideally, no recompression should be made at all, only frame rate should be changed. (Are there any codecs with varying frame rate?..)
3. Simple timeline crop tool, which does not cause recompression of the video, direct stream copy is done.

Any suggestions? At least for one or two items?

Comment: That is not "time lapse", it is just slowing down the video. Also known as "slow motion video" or possibly "time stretching".

Answer (score -1):

Adobe Premiere https://www.adobe.com/products/premiere is a feature rich video editor with a very short learning curve. With it you can import many photos, set a interval transition between then and make a time-lapse. Also when you start your project,  you can set the resolution and frame rate that you desire.

Comment: At least, it has very limited support of direct stream copy via Smart Render, which works only with narrow professional formats.